# Call java method from local html file

Tags: android, android-webview

I have local html file under my `assets` folder. I am loading this file in my `WebView` and I want to call a static Java method from my local web page.

This is what I want to do;

```
<div class="content">
<div class="welcome">
    <p>GeneralConstants.getWelcomeMessage()</p>
</div>
```

I want to call `getWelcomeMessage()` method from my local webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two way communication between JavaScript and your application is possible through `WebView.addJavascriptInterface()`. Check this example:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/09/using-webviews.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JAVA Script Interface` for communication between Android function and your java script method.

JavaScript running inside the `WebView` can call out to code in your Activity. You can use this to have your JavaScript trigger actions like starting a new activity, or it can be used to fetch data from a database or `ContentProvider`. The API for this is very simple: just call the `addJavascriptInterface`  method on your `WebView`. You pass an object whose methods you want to expose to JavaScript and the name to use when making calls.

Look at here a nice example for [Android - Webview](http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-webview.html) and [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/09/using-webviews.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Binding JavaScript code to Android code**

http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-webview.html

[Using JavaScript in WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

[Android WebView, Javascript and CSS](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/10/android-webview-javascript-and-css.html)

http://lexandera.com/tag/webview

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching this from the wrong direction. You can not access java code from the HTML page.

However, your HTML page can define a JavaScript interface and your Java code can access those. So instead of HTML page fetching the welcome message from Java code, you have Java code providing the welcome message to the HTML page.

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:setWelcomeMessage('Welcome!')");
```